# Step 1 into Android Development

Tags: android

I am yet to touch the whole android platform, jst getting my tools in order. I noticed that there is Android [4, 3, 2](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html)

What should I start on? Any IDE that is prefered?

I am reading "Learning Android By Marko Gargenta, O'REILLY Publications" as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In three steps,

1)  Eclipse Java EE Indigo from the Eclipse website (update eclipse with web address  http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7, Eclipse Menu->Help->Install New Software)

2) android sdk from google (link your eclipse with this sdk, Eclipse Menu->Window->Preferences->Android->SDK Location)

3) driver of your phone (if you want to debug on target not simulator.)

There are some example projects and simulator in sdk.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just beginning, use Eclipse. There's a [plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) especially made for android development. As far a version numbers go, it depends on who you want to target. If you only want to target tablets, using 3 and above should be fine. If you want to target phones, you're going to want to use API-level 7. That corresponds to android 2.1 which is (in my opinion) the lowest API level that still has a [significant amount of usage in the market](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html). Note that you can still access stuff from the higher api levels using the android [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Answer (score 1):

As most android documentation mentions Eclipse, I would always prefer that for starting Android development

Which Version of android you use depends of the target platform. If you code in Android 3 (Honeycomb) or higher your applications will only work on tablets, but not on most phones.

I would suggest, you start "low" for max. compatibility unless there are 3.x or 4.x features you really need.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want. Android 2 and 3 are a enstablished platform with a big reach. Android 4 will catch up easy. You should read the official guide [link](http://developer.android.com/index.html). Standard Android development is in Eclipse IDE with android plugin (described in introduction) but you could also use NetBeans or IntelliJ they both support android. First you need to understand the platform then start coding. You should really read the developer site, it helped me a lot.